# How to determine actual viewport width and height on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari, viewport

I've been stuck at such easy task as determine page width and height on iOS when the page is zoomed by the user.

The problem is that some web sites has strange layout and looks like this:

[image]

This is a not scaled page and it has resolution of 1164x1811 pixels and that's correct. I've got these values from `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`. Highlighted area is a body element and it has resolution of 1024x1594 pixels, that matters.

Next I use pinch-to-zoom to zoom page in and this is how it looks:

[image]

Now, when I trying to get page size I got 1024x1594 pixels from `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` respectively. These values are exact same to body size.

So the question is how to get the right page size whether with zoom or not.

I've tested this particular case in Chrome as well and get correct result: it's always 1164x1811 pixels regardless to zoom.

Comment: Will you please check your URL first in the browser.  Use the responsive URL to make it work properly.

Comment: @rex the thing is that I should be able to determine viewport size regardless to mobile/desktop representation of page, so switching to responsive one is not the option

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT:** Use [`document.body.clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth) and `document.body.clientHeight` to get the calculations you desire, as my original solution is now considered obsolete.

You can use <strike>`document.width` and `document.height`</strike> to retrieve the original page size on iOS Safari, even if you've pinch-zoomed.

Here's a test on the old [Space Jam site](https://www.warnerbros.com/archive/spacejam/movie/jam.htm) (which came to mind when trying to think of a site that definitely wouldn't be responsive).

[image]

Comment: strange, these properties are undefined on iOS 10.3. also these are marked as obsolete in specification :(

Comment: @nicholas_r You're absolutely right - my iOS Simulator was set to 9. I'm getting undefined in 10. Hold, please!

Comment: @nicholas_r Updated my answer - please use `document.body.clientWidth` and `document.body.clientHeight` to get the document's original dimensions when zoomed. Tested successfully in iOS 10.3.

Comment: thanks for the reply. yep, I already use these properties and it works exactly like in my question :(. you can try this out by navigating to habrahabr.ru from your iOS device and switching to desktop version. this method works in most cases, but not in all and I'm looking for any method to workaround it

Answer (score 2):

Here's a trickier but kinda useless way:
Make a page-sized element then compute/get its actual size.

```
let page_size = { height: null, width: null };
{
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    (styles => Object.keys(styles).forEach(k => div.style[k] = styles[k]))({
        height: '100vh', width: '100vw',
        position: 'fixed',
        top: '-100vh', left: '-100vw'
    })
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    page_size.height = div.offsetHeight;
    page_size.width = div.offsetWidth;
}
```

Comment: that's the way I already end up with and it doesn't work in all cases. especially in case provided in the question. you can try it by navigating to habrahabr.ru from iOS device and switching to desktop version of site